# Правильное условие для if на javascript

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть
таймер

```
<div class="timer">1100</div>
```

ник игрока

```
<div class="myanme">MyNick</div>
```

я отлавливаю таймер

```
function find_timer()
{
  var div_timer = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i = 0; i< div_timer.length; i++)
    if(div_timer[i].className == "tttimer")
      return timer_element = div_timer[i];
}
```

ник

```
function find_myname()
{
    var div_name = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i=0; i< div_name.length; i++) 
        if(div_name[i].className == "myanme") 
            return name_element = div_name[i];
}
```

как сделать правильное условие для if?

```
var value = parseInt(timer_element.innerHTML);
var myname = "Nick";
var value2 = toString.name_element; // может и не правильно тяну ник....

 if(((value2 = myname) && (value=15)))
  {}
```

хочу:

> если ((переменная мойник совпала с ником сейчас на сайте) и
>   (значение таймера = 15)), то **{..}**

на деле с другими никами тоже запускается часть **{..}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(value2 = myname) && (value=15)
```

Тут присвоение, а не сравнение.
Должно быть так:

```
(value2 === myname) && (value === 15)
```

Comment: Точно, ну с value === 15 наверное не критично?
А вот меня волнует ещё `var value2 = toString.name_element;` всё ли тут хорошо?

Comment: Нет, у вас там все плохо. name_element -  будет HTMLElement, а не его содержимое, это раз. Второе, метод `toString` надо вызывать так `name_element.toString()`.  Но вы спросили про условие, я вам и ответил про условие.

Comment: спасибо за ответы!
[ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606478/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-parseint-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)
Помогите тогда с этой частью по ссылке. Как рам там хотел это спросить, но не знал, как правильно обозвать всё это.

Comment: В вашем примере (только в том, который вы описали) правильнее бы было, как минимум возвращать так `return div_timer[i].innerHTML`. Делать `return timer_element = div_timer[i];` (т. е.зачем-то делать присвоение переменной и тут же возвращать ее - бессмысленно). InnerHTML уже вернет вам строку и тогда делать `toString()` - не надо. И еще совет, почитайте про клиентский JavaScript.

Comment: Т.е. `var value2 = name_element.innerHTML;` и (value2 === myname) сделать так и будет счастье?

Comment: ну, как бы - вроде того ) только все решение все-равно какое-то кривое )

Comment: мне хоть бы так) оптимизация и переосмысление уже после какой-то рабочей части) спасибо! очень помогли!

Comment: @J.Doe Пожалуйста :)